# python extract infomation on specific help module

Tags: python, shell

Suppose I want to get information on all the methods supported by X module in python I do this:

```
$python
>>>import X
>>> help(x)
>>> exit()
```

then I get the necessary help.
But as you can see this is time consuming process,
Instead of that what I would like to have is system similar to man pages
man x | grep 'keyword'

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`pydoc` commandline tool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html):

```
pydoc x
```

This produces the exact same documentation as `help(x)` does in the Python prompt.

You can also have it serve a HTTP server:

```
pydoc -p 4242
```

and point your browser to `http://localhost:4242` to browse Python documentation.